# How to equalize results of Partial Correlation Analysis when number of factors exceeds rows?

Tags: partial-correlation

I didn't notice this bug until I had a dataset where the number of factors was greater than my number of rows. Which lead to an overfitted perfect model when doing partial correlation (i.e. compare two models residuals).
So the correlation would be perfect, for every comparison of any given factor.

I tried to reduce the # of factors to less than then number of rows, but then I realized the closer the # of factors are to rows, the higher the correlation is which also means the greater the chance the correlation will be significant.

So I have a problem. Partial Correlation analysis is dependent on the # of factors being compared to the number of rows.

I'm not sure how to account for this. I have a rule of thumb that I should have 5*(p+2) number of records compared to p (number of predictors). So I wrote a function that splits the factors down into sets of (rows/5)-2. But this is just a rule of thumb.

I'm hoping for a simple solution, because right now I simply check if p < .8*(nrows), and if it is I don't do anything, if it's not, I then split the factors up, and then aggregate them back together until they are p < .8*(nrows).

What I'm doing is doing partial correlation on all the factors and removing the least significant one recursively until all are significant.

And I just read this http://www.psychwiki.com/wiki/How_is_a_correlation_different_than_a_partial_correlation%3F

> "You typically only conduct partial correlation when the third
>   variable has shown a relationship to one or both of the primary
>   variables. In other words, you typically first conduct correlational
>   analysis on all variables so that you can see whether there are
>   significant relationships amongst the variables, including any "third
>   variables" that may have a significant relationship to the variables
>   under investigation."

So that may be where my problem is.  But I'm not sure how I would implement that.  Would I do all pairwise as well as all 3 way comparisons and link them somewhow?  I'm trying to wrap my head around how I would code that.

Applied Regression Modelling gives an example of how to root out collinearity using regular correlation analysis.  So maybe I can compare factor A to factor B (if found correlated) controlling for Y. I.e. regress A~Y and B~Y and compare residuals.

> "Calculate the absolute values of the correlations between Y and each
>   of the quantitative predictors and between each pair of quantitiative
>   predictors; there is a potential multicollinearity problem if any of
>   the (absolute) correlations between each pair of predictors is greater
>   than the highest (Absolute) correlation between Y and each of the
>   predictors."

Comment: One approach is to leverage partial least squares regression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression. In addition, there are over 450 questions on CV which discuss it at some length.

Comment: thank you.  That actually might work for what I'm doing.  I can use partial least squares regression to do my partial correlations.  I was trying to figure out how to code something dealing with all pairwise and comparing with correlation with y and then subsequentialy doing partial correlation and it was a mess, very expensive and I couldn't fathom what to sort by (correlations between x's and y's?) to make it a backstep process.  But if I do this partial least squares... problem solved